# Delimiter inside frame being sent by UDP, split by the same delimiter

Tags: python-3.x, protocols, delimiter

Please suggest a way to handle a delimiter, say ||| inside a file which is being sent by as a part of a frame separated by |||.

```
frame_data= str(SN)+"|||"+str(flag[1])+"|||"+filepiece
```

What if ||| already exists inside the filepiece(binary data). Please suggest ways to handle it. I am using Python3. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a randomly generated separator of let's say 128 bits. The collision probability is extremely low.

Alternatively you can use length-payload coding. Since not much fits into a UDP frame anyway you can get away with 2 bytes of length N, followed by N bytes payload.

Comment: How to calculate the collision probability? For a piece of data whose length is 100MB, the collision probability is 2^(10*2)/2^128?

Comment: Take the birthday paradox into account.

Comment: Sorry, I can't  catch up. Could you please explain that in more detail for me?